# html5 canvas animation. leaving a trail and reset button

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm pretty new to this and I got the animation working by watching a youtube tutorial.
Here is a canvas animation of a keyboard controlled car.

http://jsfiddle.net/unn9P/

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.clear = function() { 
                        this.clearRect(0,0,1500,1500) };
function wait(fn)    {
                        window.setTimeout(fn, 250)    }
function repeat(fn)  {
         if (requestAnimationFrame) {
             var advance = function() {fn(); requestAnimationFrame(advance);};
             requestAnimationFrame(advance);
          } else window.setInterval(fn, 50);
}
var dx = 0, dy = 0, mousex = 0, mousey=0, mouseclicks = 0;
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var key = e.keyCode;
if (key == 37) dx=-1; 
 else if (key == 38) dy=-1; 
  else if (key == 39) dx=1; 
   else if (key == 40) dy=1; 
     else return true; 
return false;
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode; 
      if (key == 37 || key == 39) dx=0; 
       else if (key == 38 || key == 40) dy=0;
        else return true; 
      return false;
};
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
       var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
       mousex = e.clientX - rect.left; 
       mousey = e.clientY - rect.top;
};
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {mouseclicks++;};
      a = new Image();
  a.src = 'http://o.ooli.ca/car_top.png';

  wait(function(){  
        x = 50;
        y = 50;
        angle = 0;
        repeat(function() {     
                        angle = angle + dx;
                        x = x - dy * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
                        y = y - dy * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);   
                        c.clear();
                        c.translate(x, y);
                        c.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
                            c.translate(-37, -19);
                        c.drawImage(a, 0, 0);
                        c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); //reset   
        });
});
```

Now I would like to add trail behind the car as it moves along and create a reset button inside the canvas which can help me clear the trail, and bring the car to its initial position.
I have read some tutorials but i can't seem to find what I want.
Is there any idea/suggestion on how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply record your points when moving:

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/unn9P/2/)**

```
 repeat(function () {

     angle = angle + dx;
     x = x - dy * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
     y = y - dy * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);

     /// record point
     pts.push([x, y]);

     c.clear();

     /// render points (see below)
     renderTrail(pts, c);

     c.translate(x, y);
     ...
```

Then have a function to render the recorded points:

```
function renderTrail(pts, c) {
    if (pts.length > 1) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(pts[0][0], pts[0][1]);
        for(var i = 1, pt; pt = pts[i]; i++) {
            c.lineTo(pt[0], pt[1]);
        }
        c.stroke();
    }
}
```

To reset just clear the point array:

```
pts = [];
```

You can do this on a mouse-click event on the canvas where you chose to draw your button or just put a html button on top of canvas (above it, literally on top will reduce the performance of canvas).